# How to create multiple auto_increment columns in a primary key on postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables one is TABLE products which have fields (product_no int PRIMARY KEY, product_name varchar(255), price int) and TABLE orders which have fields (order_id PRIMARY KEY, product_no int, quantity int)

now I'm trying to create a new table referencing the 2 tables above and creating 2 primary key which I want to auto_increment.

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
  product_no int REFERENCES products(product_no), 
  order_id int REFERENCES orders(order_id), 
  quantity int, 
  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY(product_no, order_id)
);
```

Comment: do u need composite primary key? multiple PK isn't possible.

Comment: but i was able to create the table by removing the SERIAL data type

Comment: Just remove `serial` - it's not an attribute of the primary key, but a data type attribute for a _column_. You don't need an auto increment (identity or serial) if `(product_no, order_id)` is your primary key

Comment: Child tables should not have auto increment columns and the data must be populated from the parent tables using a Stored Procedure or Application code.

Comment: yes composite primary key. for the 3rd table i'm going to create referencing 2 tables and the 3rd table i want the primary key to auto_increment

Comment: okay i got it thanks

Comment: @Dan Why do you even have 3 tables? Your third table has the same columns as your second. Did you mean to remove the `product_no` and `quantity` from the `orders` table?

Comment: This design is broken. As @Bergi commented you are duplicating information. It probably should be something like `orders.order_id`<-->`order_items.order_id` and then `order_items.product_no`<-->`products.product_no`.  Though I generally name the child FK field something like `order_items.order_id_fk`, `order_items.product_no_fk` to make things clearer when building queries.

Comment: Is it not to allow multiple different products in a single order? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: It would allow different products for a single order, it would not allow two rows that have the same `product_no` for a given `order_id`. This assumes the `serial` is dropped. But the same thing could be done with `UNIQUE(product_no, order_id)` and have a `serial` PK on a `orders_items.line_id` field.